# How to query on mysql prompt to distinguish between NULL and "NULL" (varchar)?

Tags: mysql

I've got this row when querying a `unit` table:

```
mysql> select * from unit where id=136\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                                     id: 136
                           canonical_id: 0
                             digit_code: 136
                             ascii_code: dBm
                                   name: decibel-milliwatts
                                 symbol: dBm
                             multiplier: NULL
                                 offset: NULL
                              canonical: 1
                                   temp: NULL
```

But when running mysqldump for the same row I've got this:

```
INSERT INTO `unit` VALUES (136,0,135,'dBm','decibel-milliwatts','dBm','NULL','NULL',1,'NULL');
```

As you can see the `NULL` values are actually strings with the content `'NULL'` what is not visible from the terminal.

Is there anyway to get something like this where querying from the prompt?

```
                                 id: 136
                       canonical_id: 0
                         digit_code: 136
                         ascii_code: 'dBm'
                               name: 'decibel-milliwatts'
                             symbol: 'dBm'
                         multiplier: 'NULL'
                             offset: 'NULL'
                          canonical: 1
                               temp: 'NULL'
```

Comment: `INSERT ... VALUES (... , NULL , ...)` inserts `NULL`. `INSERT ... VALUES (... , 'NULL' , ...)` inserts a string which contains `'NULL'`.

Comment: No clear! Do you want NULL or 'NULL'

Comment: @RiggsFolly what is not clear? I would like to get (on the prompt) `"NULL"` if the value is `"NULL"`, and `NULL` if the value is `NULL`.

Comment: Have you tried all other outputformats? Is there a specific reason you only use the shell and not something with a gui/tui?

Comment: @inetphantom in this case, I can just use the mysql prompt. Thanks for the edit!